# Use python struct.error to stop a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small function for my programm (python) which writes some data into a csv file. The input data is from an other file. Both files are opened!
The code for actual read- and writeprocess is:

```
while aux != '':
     data = f.read(4)
     data = unpack('I', data)
     data = list(data)
     writer.writerow(data)
else:
     print('done')
```

This code works fine so far, but sometimes my input data doesn't have left 4 bytes at the end for the last readprocess, so it gives me the error "struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4".

This is totally fine for me, i don't mind some dataloss at the end but this error stops my whole programm. 
Is there a way to stop the function and return to the main programm if this error occours? Or just stop the while loop und go on with the "else:" part?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Errors and exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: You seem to have mixed up `data` and `aux`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Wrote this question in a hurry and mixed some of my variables ... fixed it in my original post!

Comment: @Kevin thanks, this was really helpfull and i could solve my issue : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
try:
    data = unpack('I', data)
except struct.error as err:
    print(err)
```

This way you'll know when there is a problem, but program execution will continue.

Do read up on [Python error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for the full story.